# "Show output from" switches to Tests when I start building the solution. How can I avoid this?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

[image]

I want it to show output from **Build** by default. But somehow, whenever I start building or cleaning solution, the selection changes to Tests, which is irrelevant to me. Is there a way to edit those options and delete Tests altogether?

Answer (score 0):

[Alexandru] Disable the following Visual Studio Extensions

- "Test Adapter for Google Test"
- "Test Adapter for Boost.Test"